# playwright-test: test that input is required

Tags: playwright, required, html-input, playwright-test

I have an input for a login form that is required:

```
<input
  autoComplete="email"
  defaultValue={email}
  disabled={state === 'submitting'}
  id="email"
  name="email"
  placeholder={t('user-authentication:email-placeholder')}
  required // HERE!
  type="email"
/>
```

How can I test that the input is required with Playwright? My native browser warning in Chromium is: "Please fill in this field."

[image: Chrome input warning saying "please fill in this field"]

Is there a way to check / assert for this warning in Playwright? Or another way to test that the input is required?

I tried writing nothing in the input with `.fill('')` and then pressing enter with `page.keyboard.press('Enter')`, but those did not cause the warning to show up.

Comment: Try this. Add empty space in input field `fill(' ')`. Then press `Backspace`  `page.keyboard.press('Backspace')`.

Comment: What about pressing Enter directly, without using fill()? The pop up should appear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the message is displayed by the browser and not something added to the DOM, you would struggle to test it directly in Playwright.

You could check the the `required` attribute is present, and trust that the browser is going to display the warning.

```js
await page.locator('input#email[required]')
```

There's also a [Constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required#constraint_validation) you could apply

> If the element is required and the element's value is the empty string, then the element is suffering from valueMissing and the element will match the `:invalid` pseudo class.

```js
await page.locator('input#email[required]:invalid')
```

Comment: I am agree with Layla. If the field is required, the browser should show the alert, you have to trust on the browser, if the browser is not working you will not be able to solve yourself, so I think it is a good validation. If it is not enough for you maybe you need to talk with developers to add some other kind of errors.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working Playwright code of testing browser native warning message (tested for Chrome):

```js
    import { expect, test} from '@playwright/test';
    
    test('has warning message presented', async ({ page }) => {
      await page.goto('https://q94u5.csb.app/');
      const email = page.getByRole('textbox')
      const submit = page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Submit' });
      
      await email.fill('x');
      await submit.click();
    
      
      const validationMessage = await email.evaluate((element) => {
        const input = element as HTMLInputElement
        return input.validationMessage
      })
    
      expect(validationMessage).toContain("Please include an '@' in the email address. 'x' is missing an '@'.")
    });
```

As you can see, you can catch `validationMessage` in Playwright but is not recommended to test it. It is browser responsibility to deliver this element (and it is not responsibility of the webpage itself).

Read more about build-in validation here:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/validation/

More elements information can be extracted this way:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation
and go to chapter **Validating forms using JavaScript** to check available methods